# Laravel 10 Breeze - Throw custom flash message if user is not active

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade, flash-message, laravel-breeze

What I am trying to do is throw a custom error message if the user is not active.

This is the method:

```
public function authenticate(): void
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password') + ['is_active' => true] , $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
        
        
        if(Auth::user()->is_active == 0){
            Session::flash('active', 'User is not active.'); 
        }

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

Then in the blade file:

```
 @if(Session::has('active'))
        <div class="bg-red-100 border-t-4 border-red-500 rounded-b text-teal-900 px-4 py-3 shadow-md mb-6" role="alert">
            <div class="flex align-center justify-center">
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">{{ Session::get('active') }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 @endif
```

And when I try to login I get `Attempt to read property "is_active" on null`

I also added `is_active` in `protected $fillable`

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password')` means if auth failed to execute the `if` condition.  So if auth failed there is no way you can access `Auth::user()`. Because it's `null` always.

Alternatively you can do something like this

```
public function authenticate(): void
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    $user = User::where('email', $this->input('email'))->first();

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($this->input('password'), $user->password)) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        if ($user && $user->is_active === 0) {
            Session::flash('active', 'User is not active.');
        }

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    Auth::login($user, $this->boolean('remember'));
    // if you need you can set is_active  tru once logged in

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

Comment: This does work, but when i enter the correct email but wrong password, it gives me the message that it's not active. So it doesn't matter if the password is correct it only checks email.

Comment: If you want to log in and then throw the not active validation you can swap `is_active` checking line with the ` Auth::login`